# Chrome on Mac UTF-8 in URL strange behavior

Tags: google-chrome

I have URLs with non-ascii chars that behave strangely on Chrome 79 on Catalina 10.15.3 
I was not able to reproduce it with Chrome 79 on Windows, neither with Safari.

If I have the following chain in the URL bar `∀ ∀∀∀§`, the last three `∀` get bigger then the first one. Try copy pasting it in your Chrome URL bar. If I remove the `§` or put a space before the `§`, all the `∀` return to the same (smaller) size.

[image]

google.com does not seem to care about the size difference in the URL, but my Java WebServer is not able to parse the URL if the `∀` and `§` are adjacents.

**Update** : I've just upgraded to Chrome 80 and the problem does not appear any more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be the case with all tall characters at the end, for example the `dagger(†)`(U+2020), the double `dagger(‡)`(U+2021) and `box drawings light vertical and horizontal(┼)`(U+253C) show the same effect.
My guess is that chrome doesn't handle those "tall" characters well and tries to show all characters in a "word", limited by for example a space or a comma, as the same height.
I also could not find another place in macOS where this was the case, so I guess it is a chrome Bug. You can file a bug report in the menu under the help section or [in the google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: It seems very logical, but now that I have Chrome 80, I cannot reproduce it anymore :-(Also, I will not file an issue since it is corrected in Chrome 80, but feel free to do so. Thanks